# gcloud commands with --flatten or --format not working on Windows CMD or BAT

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, cmd, command-line-interface, gcloud

The following [gcloud command using the `--format` option](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#listing_the_versions_of_an_image):

```
gcloud container images list-tags --format='value(digest)' [MY_IMAGE_URL]
```

Will run fine in a `sh` or `bash` (eg. through CMDER or Git Bash), yet will break if run from Command Prompt or within a CMD or BAT script:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.list-tags) Name expected [
    table(
        digest.slice(7:19).join(''),
        tags.list(),
        timestamp.date():optional,
        BUILD_DETAILS.buildDetails.provenance.sourceProvenance.context.cloudRepo.revisionId.notnull().list().slice(:8).join(''):optional:label=GIT_SHA,
        vuln_counts.list():optional:label=VULNERABILITIES,
        IMAGE_BASIS.derivedImage.sort(distance).map().extract(baseResourceUrl).slice(:1).map().list().list().split('//').slice(1:).list().split('@').slice(:1).list():optional:label=FROM,
        BUILD_DETAILS.buildDetails.provenance.id.notnull().list():optional:label=BUILD,
        DISCOVERY[0].discovered.analysisStatus:optional:label=VULNERABILITY_SCAN_STATUS
    )
 *HERE* 'value(digest)':(timestamp:sort=1:reverse)].
```

I've seen this `Name expected ... *HERE*` error occur with other Google Cloud Platform commands too. When the commands are run without any `--format` or `--flatten` modifiers they execute fine.

Any idea why this happens and how to prevent it?

*Running most recent gcloud components: `Google Cloud SDK 290.0.1, core 2020.04.24`*

Comment: Replace single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Comment: I happened to see this error when running in via Python's `subprocess.run`. To resolve, had to remove the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` solves the problem on Windows.